# how could I change the opacity of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in javascript and I am trying to change the opacity of a div and I don't know how to do it, and I didn't find anything online.
here is my code so far:
Javascript

```
function close_images(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("modificar_imagen").style.opacity="0";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="modificar_imagen">
        <div class="close1" onclick="close_images()"><img src="img/icons/close.png" alt="close"></div>
            <div class="contenido">
                <div class="grid">
                        <div  class="image_user"><img src="img/user1.jpg"></div>
                        <div  class="image_user"><img src="img/user1.jpg"></div>


                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("modificar_imagen")[0].style.opacity="0";

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("modificar_imagen")` retrieves a HTMLCollection. It would be better to use `document.querySelectorAll()` so that you can use the `forEach()` method to iterate over the image collection:

```
    document.querySelectorAll(".modificar_imagen").forEach(el=>el.style.opacity="0");
```

That should do it.

```js
function close_images(){
    document.querySelectorAll(".modificar_imagen").forEach(el=>el.style.opacity="0");
}

close_images()
```

```html
<div class="modificar_imagen">
        <div class="close1" onclick="close_images()"><img src="img/icons/close.png" alt="close"></div>
            <div class="contenido">
                <div class="grid">
                        <div  class="image_user"><img src="img/user1.jpg"></div>
                        <div  class="image_user"><img src="img/user1.jpg"></div>


                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Would using a getElementbyId() return a single element?

Comment: @Magnus - it would, but there are no ids on the images. It is much better to use the more modern `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` methods. Then one simply uses CSS selectors to choose one or more elements.

Comment: @RitwickDey - fixed. Thanks.